# Nested CSS dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

So I've been trying to get this dropdown menu to work properly for past few hours and I'm having no luck.

The HTML is:

```
<nav>
 <ul id="#sideNavArchive">
  <li><a>Year</a></li>
   <ul>
    <li><a>Month</a></li>
    <li><a>Month</a></li>
   </ul>
  <li><a>Year</a></li>
   <ul>
    <li><a>Month</a></li>
    <li><a>Month</a></li>
   </ul> 
  </ul>
 </nav>
```

Now, all I'm looking to do is hover of Year and for the months to drop down, but I seem to be running into trouble with the CSS selectors.

The CSS I have at the moment:

```
ul#sideNavArchive > li{background-color:red; display:block;}
ul#sideNavArchive > ul > li{display:none;}
ul#sideNavArchive > li:hover ul > li{display:block;}
```

There's obviously something with that bottom piece of css which is causing the issue, if someone could point it out to me that'd be great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the typo, I think you are looking for something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jbaum012/dekYZ/

```
#sideNavArchive > li{background-color:red; display:block;}
#sideNavArchive > ul > li{display:none;}
#sideNavArchive > li:hover + ul > li{display:block;}
```

Comment: Yea sorry about the typos ignore them, but yes that's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your markup. You don't need the `#` symbol. Change this:

```
<ul id="#sideNavArchive">..</ul>
```

to this:

```
<ul id="sideNavArchive">..</ul>
```

[Working example (UPDATED)](http://jsfiddle.net/dekYZ/1/)

Additionally, you can reduce the specificity of your targeting, and just target the direct descendent `ul` (sub-menu), rather than specifying each `li` contained therein:

```
#sideNavArchive > ul { display: none; }
#sideNavArchive > li:hover + ul { display: block; }
```

Comment: Ah yes sorry for the typos, the answer I was looking for was the "+" selector and yes you're right I could just use the ul instead of going down to the li, I just used the css in this case to be more specific in what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem was that you were closing the `li` too early

```
 <li><a>Year</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a>Month</a></li>
    <li><a>Month</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

is the proper structure.

[**JSFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/5MeCb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a>Year<a>
      <ul>
           <a>Month</a>
           <a>Month</a>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a>Year<a>
      <ul>
           <a>Month</a>
           <a>Month</a>
      </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#nav{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
}
#nav li{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;
}
#nav a{
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
}
#nav ul{
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
}
#nav ul li{
    padding-top:1px;
    float:none;
}
#nav li:hover ul{ 
    top: 10px;
    left:-40px;
}
```

It's basically done in the `#nav ul` where `left` is `-9999px;` which means out of the screen, by hovering it gets in the screen.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UzCSM/)